# Server-side task to query Office 365 account for new emails

Tags: c#, outlook, office365

I need a server-side task on my .NET 4.6.1/MVC 5 app that will periodically check a specific O365 email address for new emails and retrieve them if found. This seems like a stupidly simple task, but I cannot find documentation *anywhere* for creating a server-side process to accomplish this. The only documentation Microsoft seems to have is for OAuth2 and passing through credentials when users sign in. I don't want that. I want to check one specific account, that's it. How would I accomplish this?

These are the pages I've found. There are others, but all are along these lines.

- [Intro to the Outlook API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/use-outlook-rest-api) - I don't see a way to use a service account with the v2 endpoint.
- [Get Started with the Outlook REST APIs](https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/dotnet) - This is specific to logging users in with OAuth2, unhelpful for my purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Intro to the Outlook API - I don't see a way to use a service account with the v2 endpoint.

The v2 endpoint doesn’t support client credential at present( refer to the [limitation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-limitations/)). You need to register/configure the app using Azure portal and use the original endpoint to authenticate the app. More detail about register the app please refer to [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/platform/rest). And we need to ‘read mail in all mailbox’ to use the client credential to read the messages like figure below.
[image]

And here is the code that using client credential to read messages using the Microsoft Graph:

```
string clientId = "";
string clientsecret = "";
string tenant = "";
string resourceURL = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant + "/oauth2/token";
string userMail = "";
var accessToken = new TokenHelper(authority).AcquireTokenAsync(clientId, clientsecret, resourceURL);

  var graphserviceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
   new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
       (requestMessage) =>
       {
           requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);

           return Task.FromResult(0);
       }));

        var items = await graphserviceClient.Users[user].Messages.Request().OrderBy("receivedDateTime desc").GetAsync();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Subject);
        }

class TokenHelper
{
    AuthenticationContext authContext;

    public TokenHelper(string authUri)
    {
        authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authUri);
    }

    public string AcquireTokenAsync(string clientId, string secret,string resrouceURL)
    {
        var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId: clientId, clientSecret: secret);
        var result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resrouceURL, credential).Result;
        return result.AccessToken;
    }

}
```

In addition, if we authenticate the app with code grant flow we can also create a subscription which notify the app when the mail box receive the new messages.( refer to [webhoocks/subscription](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/webhooks))